# How do I pass parameters to my Zend Framework plugins during instantiation?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have defined a plugin on the `libraries` path, using the correct directory structure, and have made it's presence known in the `application.ini` file. The plugin loads, and my `preDispatch()` method fires. But, how can I pass parameters to the plugin during instantiation?

Here is my code:

```
class Project_Controller_Plugin_InitDB extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    private $_config = null;

    public function __contruct($config){
        $this->_config = $config;
    }

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $db = Zend_DB::factory("Pdo_Mysql", $this->_config);
        Zend_Registry::set("db", $db);
    }

}
```

Specifically, how do I pass `$config` to the `__construct()` method?

Thanks,

**Solution**

Here is what I ended up with (Thanks to Phil Brown!):

In my `application.ini` file:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "MyProjectName_"
```

In my `Bootstrap.php` file:

```
protected function _initFrontControllerPlugins() {
    $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');

    $plugin = new MyProjectName_Controller_Plugin_InitDB($this->_config->resources->db->params);
    $frontController->registerPlugin($plugin);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply register your plugin manually in your `Bootstrap` class

```
protected function _initFrontControllerPlugins()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');

    // Config could come from app config file
    // or anywhere really
    $config = $this->getOption('initDb');

    $plugin = new Project_Controller_Plugin_InitDB($config);
    $frontController->registerPlugin($plugin);
}
```

Comment: Right, AFAIK, if your plugin requires parameters, you cannot instantiate it purely via `application.ini`. You need to instantiate manually during bootstrap, passing the parameters there, as outlined above.

Comment: @David Whilst I prefer the method in my answer, you could always pull the 'bootstrap' invokeArg out of the front controller instance in the plugin which would give you access to the config and resources. This relies on the singleton nature of the FC though which I always try and discourage anyway

Comment: Brown: Absolutely. If the plugin requires params from config, best to actually pass them at instantiation, rather than have the plugin pull them from the singleton FC. Go DI #FTW. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Zend Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html)

Answer (score -1):

Have you read [this](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Config+Usage+in+Constructors+and+Factories+-+Bill+Karwin)? $Config structure resembles Zend_Config very closely, so if you wish to pass extra parameters, treat it as an array of key/values.

Comment: I do have my database information stored in my `application.ini`, so I suppose I could directly reference that in my plugin. But, how could I pass parameters (like I have suggested) to other plugins that don't have Zend_Config info?